# How to send json response and file at the same time?

Tags: node.js, image, express, file

I want to  send json response and file at the same time.

I mean I want to return user information and the picture of the user with the same response.

for returning the image as a file I am using this:

```
const imagePath = getAbsoluteImagePath(result.image);//C:\Users\**\images\paper-1706098749930-569585663.jpg
res.status(200).sendFile(imagePath);
```

edit user route :

```
.put(authMiddleware,(req, res, next) => {
 upload_image.single('image')(req, res, (err: any) => {
if (err instanceof multer.MulterError && err.code === 'LIMIT_FILE_SIZE') { return next(new HttpException(400, `File too large. Maximum size is 0.5 MB`));} else if (err) {return next(new HttpException(400, err.message));}next();});
},
handleCreateUser,
editUserValidator,
errorHandlerValidator,
checkPermissionsMiddleware(Resource.USER),
UsersController.editUser,
)
```

response of this is message: "user is updated successfully "

get user route :

```
.get(authMiddleware,checkPermissionsMiddleware(Resource.USER), UsersController.getUser);
```

get user controller:

```
public getItem = async (req: RequestWithUser, res: Response, next: NextFunction): Promise<void> => {
    try {
      const { id } = req.params;
      const result = await this.itemsService.getItem({
        id: Number(id),
      });
      const imagePath = getAbsoluteImagePath(result.image);  
      res.status(200).sendFile(imagePath);
    } catch (e) {
      next(e);
    }
  };
```

When uploading an image, I am using multer for the process.
On the front end, I attempt to call the 'get user info' endpoint, which is expected to contain user information along with the image for editing purposes.
It's important to note that the user info in the body request is in 'data-form' to facilitate image upload. If I send the image as a base64 encoded string, the front end will resend it to the body request of the 'edit user' endpoint in the same format as received (in case there are no changes to the user's image). This is where the issue arises, as multer is unable to interpret the base64 encoded version

Front end: Modify user module by invoking the "get user" endpoint to retrieve all user information. Subsequently, implement the required changes and send the "edit user" request.

I want the getUser endpoint to return both user information and the image, with the image being interpreted as a file using multer.

Comment: You can not respond to _one_ single HTTP request, with more than one content type.

Comment: You _could_ stick the image data _into_ your JSON, base64 encoded. But then you would have to extract it from there again and turn it into an image, on the receiving end.

Comment: @CBroe When uploading an image, I am using multer for the process. On the front end, I attempt to call the 'get user info' endpoint, which is expected to contain user information along with the image for editing purposes. It's important to note that the user info in the body request is in 'data-form' to facilitate image upload in edit user endpoint.

Comment: @CBroe If I send the image as a base64 encoded string, the front end will resend it to the body request of the 'edit user' endpoint in the same format as received (in case there are no changes to the user's image). As multer is unable to interpret the base64 encoded version.

Comment: Request the image separately from the JSON then, in a new request ...? (Can't tell if that would work in your existing setup, because you just gave a vague, ambiguous verbal explanation so far. Please go read [ask] and [mre] - we like to see relevant code here.)

Comment: @CBroe check the updates

Answer (score 0):

On backend, read the file and include it in result object, and return JSON response:

```
const image = fs.readFileSync(imagePath);

result.imagePreview = image;

res.json(result);
```

On frontend, convert image to Blob-> URL.string (or base64) to enable preview:

Example with Blob:

```
const res = await fetch('/getItemRoute');

const result = await res.json();

// convert JSON Buffer to file
const imageAsFile =new Blob([new Uint8Array(result.imagePreview.data)], {
  type: 'image/jpeg',
});
const preview = URL.createObjectURL(imageAsFile);

document.querySelector('#img').src = preview;
```

Later, if the image has been modified, include the new image file for request for Multer (as File/Blob, not base64):

```
 formData.append('image', newImage);
 // upload edited data
 // fetch('/edit-user', {method:'PUT', body: formData})...

// on backend: if req.file -> overwrite image
```